# Why doesn't this javascript code process this xml file?

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","css/galerii.xml",false)
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
alert(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("GALERIE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
</script>
```

to process some xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<GALERIES>
<GALERIE>
info
</GALERIE>

<GALERIE>
other info
</GALERIE>
</GALERIES>
```

But I get nothing in the alert and shouldn't xmlhttp.open("GET","css/galerii.xml",false) have a value if it's successful ? It's undefined.
There's a root node now, same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no root node (document element), which is a requirement in XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<GALERIES>
  <GALERIE>
    info
  </GALERIE>

  <GALERIE>
    other info
  </GALERIE>
</GALERIES>
```

You also have no onreadystatechange method for your AJAX request. When your code which reads the responeXML executes, the http request for the XML has yet to return. You need to read up on how to build AJAX requests: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xmlhttprequest

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/2F8q6/1/

Your JS modified to work as the example does:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.open( "GET","css/galerii.xml", false );

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if( xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200 )
        {
            xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
            alert(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("GALERIE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.send();
</script>
```

Comment: I got the same result even with a root node.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I made a new page just with this script in the body and I get nothing. What could be wrong. By the way shouldn't xmlhttp.open( "GET","css/galerii.xml", false ); have true as the third parameter ? I tried both ways but still nothing.

Comment: At this point I don't know what else may be wrong with your script. If you're able to make a version of the broken script available for access online, shoot me a link and I'll take a look.

Comment: I tried putting another alert inside the if() and I didn't get a response so I thought one of the conditions is never met. I deleted xmlhttp.status === 200 and it went through I got my alert but not the xml alert. Any ideas ? What alternatives do I have if this doesn't work ?

Comment: readyState of 4 means the request is complete, status is the HTTP status that was returned from the server. When readyState is 4, if status is not 200 something went wrong with the request. What are you getting for status when readyState is 4?

Comment: I uploaded the 2 files on my hosting account and it works like a charm, status is 200 and the xml alert returns info, wow ! But why doesn't this work on my computer ?

Comment: That depends...are you running a web server on your computer, or just using the local filesystem? The latter woudnD't work as XHR's job is to make HTTP requests to a server. Glad it's working1

Answer (score 1):

XML document may only have one root element.

Answer (score 1):

You need a single root element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<GALERIES>
  <GALERIE>
    info
  </GALERIE>
  <GALERIE>
    other info
  </GALERIE>
</GALERIES>
```

Answer (score 0):

fix your xml . your xml is not valid. there is no root element in your xml. 
try here
http://www.w3schools.com/Dom/dom_validate.asp.